# How to manually trigger view model item change notifications

Tags: extjs

There is a custom ExtJS component with controller, view, and model all in their own classes. View model looks like this

```
Ext.define( 'SomeEditorViewModel', {
  extend    : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
  alias     : 'someeditor',

  data      : {
    quote               : 10,
    bookmark            : 20,
    group               : 300,
    validity            : Ext.Date.today(),
    equipment           : []
  },
  formulas : {
    // etc.
  }
```

In the controller there are several 'on change' subscriptions linked to specific pieces of 'data' object. Besides that there are nested custom components, not listed here, which are also subscribed to change notifications issued by the owning component.

Sometimes I need to trigger all the handlers of say 'group' value to make all the subscriptions execute without actually changing the value of 'group', it must remain what it is.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could fire your own custom "refresh" - event:

```
Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('groupRefresh');
```

An in your Component(s) controller add the following:

```
Ext.define('Frontend.view.main.CustomComponent',
{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    listen: {
        global: {
            groupRefresh: 'onGroupRefresh',
        }
    }

    onGroupRefresh: function() {
      //call multiple handlers, update components, etc...
    }
}
```